# Finding trouble with tab navigator in different version of IOS

Tags: react-native

I'm using tab navigator in my project and using an image as well as label in  my tab but i'm not able to find exact solution for aligning them together as their show differently in different versions of IOS. Here is my code, i am having 2 tab navigators; outerTab and innerTab.

I have aligned icon and label column wise in bottom tabbar and row wise in top tab bar navigator.

Please find the attached image where you can find alignment issues of both bottom and top tab navigator.

```
export const OuterTab = TabNavigator({

tanks: {
    screen: TanksStack,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Tanks',
        tabBarIcon: (
            <Image source={require('../logos/tab_assets.png')}
            style={[styles.icon, {color: '#ffffff'}]}
            />
        )
    },
},
alerts: {
    screen: AlertsStack,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Alerts',
        tabBarIcon: (
            <Image source={require('../logos/tab_alerts.png')}
            style={[styles.icon, {color: '#ffffff'}]}
            />
        )
    },
},
Settings: {
    screen: Setting,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
        tabBarIcon: (
            <Image source={require('../logos/tab_settings.png')}
            style={[styles.icon, {color: '#ffffff'}]}
            />
        )
    },
},
},
{
tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  animationEnabled: true,
  swipeEnabled:false,
  tabBarOptions: {
    upperCaseLabel: false,
    showIcon: true,
    activeBackgroundColor:'#2394C7',
    inactiveBackgroundColor:'grey',
    tabStyle:{
      marginTop:(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 0 : 10,
      height : 53,

    },
     indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor : '#2394C7',
        height :(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 53 :  63,
      },

     style :{
         backgroundColor:'grey'
     },
    labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 15,
        fontWeight:'bold',
         marginTop: 0,
         color :'#ffffff'
    },
  },
});
```

and innerTab code:

```
export const InnerTab = TabNavigator({
Map: {
    screen: MapStack,
    navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel: 'Map',
          tabBarIcon:  (
                <Image source={require('../logos/map.png')}
                style={[styles.icon, {color: '#ffffff'}]}
                />
          )
    },
},
List: {
    screen: ListStack,
    navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel: 'List',
          tabBarIcon:  (
                <Image source={require('../logos/list.png')}
                style={[styles.icon, {color: '#ffffff'}]}
                />
          )
    },
},
},
{
tabBarPosition: 'top',
  animationEnabled: true,
  swipeEnabled:false,
  tabBarOptions: {
    upperCaseLabel: false,
    showIcon: true,
    activeBackgroundColor:'#2394C7',
    inactiveBackgroundColor:'grey',
    tabStyle:{

      marginTop:(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 0 : 10,
      height : 53,
      flexDirection : 'row' ,
      justifyContent : 'center',
      alignItems : 'center'


    },
     indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor : '#2394C7',
        height :(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 53 :  63,
      },

     style :{

         backgroundColor:'grey'
     },
    labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 15,
        fontWeight:'bold',
        color :'#ffffff'
    },
  },
});
```

Any lead will be greatly appreciated.

[image: topTab and bottomTab]